# how to navigate between tabitem with Left and Right Key in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

hi everybody I want used shortcut key (using left and right key) in wpf and tabcontrol to navigation between tabitem
 I set code in `Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)`

like this:

```
switch (e.Key)
            {
                case Key.Right:
                    if (tbControl.TabIndex == 0)
                        tbControl.TabIndex = 1;
                    break;

                case Key.Left:
                    if (tbControl.TabIndex == 0)
                        tbControl.TabIndex = 1;
                    break;
            }
```

but it's not do anything 
I want navigation between tabitem with left and right key
thanks

Comment: Does your method get called? Put a breakpoint in it and debug it.

Comment: I guess you want to capture a "global keyhook"..

Comment: @nvoigt yes I used breakpoint but not detected keydown!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [`TabControl.TabIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx) when you should be using [`TabControl.SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Right:
            if (tbControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
                tbControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
            break;
        case Key.Left:
            if (tbControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
                tbControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

`TabIndex` is common to all controls, and represents the order in which controls are focused when the user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. `SelectedIndex` is specific to selector controls (e.g. `TabControl`, `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, etc.) and represents the index of the currently selected item in said control.

Also, if you wanted this to work with more than two tabs, I would change your `case` statements to something more like this:

```
case Key.Right:
    if (tbControl.SelectedIndex < tbControl.Items.Count - 1)
        tbControl.SelectedIndex++;
    break;

case Key.Left:
    if (tbControl.SelectedIndex > 0)
        tbControl.SelectedIndex--;
    break;
```